# Серая папка GitHub

Tags: xcode, github

Сделал commit на GitHub. Закинул туда [**весь проект**](https://github.com/YuryBandarchuk16/Add1Game/tree/master/Add%201). Почему-то папка светится серым цветом и нет доступа к тому, что лежит в той папке.

Проект из Xcode. Почему такое может быть?

Comment: Эта иконка недоступного сабмодуля. То есть либо у вас у сабмодуля путь не прописан, либо у вас отдельная репа внутри этой папки, которую он подцепил как сабмодуль. Раз "закинули весь проект", скорее всего второе. Можно просто эту репу (в смысле служебные файлы гита внутри этой папки) грохнуть и перезалить уже без них.

Comment: А как удалить все служебные файлы гита?
Просто никаких лишних файлов в этой папке у меня нет.

Comment: Попробуйте грохнуть папку .git внутри серой папки, если она там есть. То есть что я имею в виду, возможно у вас была репа в папке Add 1, при заливке вы создали еще одну репу, в родительской директории, и она решила что в папке Add 1 - подмодуль

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, опубликуйте, пожалуйста, ваш комментарий как ответ.

Comment: @Arhad, done...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта иконка недоступного сабмодуля.

То есть либо у вас у сабмодуля путь не прописан, либо у вас отдельный репозиторий внутри этой папки, который он подцепил как сабмодуль. Раз "закинули весь проект", скорее всего второе. Можно просто этот репозиторий (в смысле служебные файлы гита внутри этой папки) грохнуть и перезалить уже без них.

Попробуйте удалить папку .git внутри серой папки, если она там есть.
То есть, возможно у вас был репозиторий в папке Add 1, при заливке Вы создали еще один репозиторий, в родительской директории, и git решил что в папке Add 1 - подмодуль